# How can I say I know a little more Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I think I'm correct when I say:

> PAVCVS PLVS LATINE SCIO

> little more Latin I know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that is not correct. “A little more” is *paulo plus*. (Technically that is a neuter ablative: “by a little.”) You could also say *paulum plus* (technically an adverb) or *paululo* or *paululum*; all these are fine. Another option would be *aliquantulo* (the deminutive of *aliquanto*, which means “quite a bit”). Note: all these work with any comparative you throw at them, e.g. *paulo minus* “a little less,” *paulo melius* “a little better” and so on.

There would be nothing inherently grammatically wrong with *pauco*, although, as cmw points out, the singular of that word is relatively rare. Ultimately though, the thing is that the Romans just didn't use it that way.

Knowing Latin is *linguam Latinam scire*.

More of Latin is *plus linguae Latinae*.

So I would say:

> Paulo plus linguae Latinae scio (quam tu/hodie quam hesterno die/etc.)

Comment: And just to add on to this, *paucus* is "few" and is chiefly found in the plural (like "few things" or "few words" etc.).

Comment: Sebastian Koppehel: In "...hodie quam hesterno die" isn't "quam" omitted in an ablative-of-comparion? The inclusion of "quam" requires the two compared nouns to be in the same case, doesn't it?

Comment: @tony it's no ablative of comparison, it's an ablative of time. And *hodie* is not a noun.