# "the man who knew everything, and even a little more"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I was reading a bit about Pico della Mirandola and noticed that his birthday was tomorrow. And I came across a quote attributed to the French writer Voltaire "the man who knew everything, and even a little more."
I have a feeling that in Latin you can have an impactful translation

vir qui omnia sciebat, et paulo plus

What do you think
I am open to fairly lose translations

Answer (score 9):

The French Wikipedia article on [Pic de la Mirandole](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Pic_de_la_Mirandole) features a header **Pic de la Mirandole, Pascal et Voltaire**.

> Pascal (...) se moque (...) implicitement de [Pico] dans Les Pensées, en faisant allusion à ceux qui prétendent discourir « de omni re scibili » (« de toute chose connaissable ») *[12]* ; ce à quoi Voltaire aurait ajouté : « et quibusdam aliis » (« et sur quelques autres »).

> Pascal implicitly makes fun of Pico in his Pensées, when he alludes to those who are liable to talk **de omni re scibili**; to which Voltaire supposedly added **et quibusdam aliis**.

*[12]* is a footnote which can be translated as *Pico's own motto*

Comment: So something like *vir qui de omni re scibili colloqui potuit*?

Answer (score 1):

JobRozemund's answer is a good one, but is it possible to approach the OP's request more faithfully? The tricky bit is, "a little more"; these "more-or-less" things, in Latin, are not necessarily straightforward. Job stepped around this with the adroitness of a mountain goat, deploying Voltaire's: "et quibusdam aliis" = "and with certain other (things)".

Seb, in his answer: https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/16301/1982, used an ablative, "paulo plus" = "(by) a little more".

> "qui intellegat de omni re scibili et paulo plus." =

> "He who may understand concerning all things discernible, and (even) a little more."